# VBA macro assigned to checkbox with parameter corrupts workbook

Tags: excel, vba

When I assign this macro to hide or unhide a worksheet to a checkbox with a parameter, and then save, I get an error on opening the sheet the next time stating that the file needs to be repaired, followed up by another message "Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.bin part (Workbook)".

[image]

This workbook has no other macros, and has no named ranges. Despite this error, the macro functions as expected. If I delete the macro then save and reopen the workbook *twice*, the error does not return. How can I prevent this?

[image]

The assignment to the checkbox is:
`Book1.xlsb!'Sheet1.HideUnhideSheets("Sheet2")'`

```
Public Sub HideUnhideSheets(s As String, Optional flag As String, Optional cbnumber As String)
 
Dim Data As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox
Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s)
If cbnumber <> "" Then
    Set cb = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(cbnumber)
End If

'if flag is set, set visibility to the flag
'if cbnumber is set, toggle the checkbox
If flag = "Hide" Then
    Data.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    If cbnumber <> "" Then
        cb.Value = xlOff
    End If
ElseIf flag = "unhide" Then
    Data.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    If cbnumber <> "" Then
        cb.Value = xlOn
    End If

'if flag is not set, toggle
ElseIf flag = "" Then
    If Data.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
    Data.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Else
    Data.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
End If
 
Set Data = Nothing
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure it would help, here are a couple things: assign a default value each of your `Optional` parameters. This guarantees a known value when the routine is entered. Using `cbnumber` as an index implies that it's a number - maybe it's not. Use `IsNumeric` to check and/or convert it explicitly to a number value with `CLong`.

Comment: @PeterT I added default values for both `Optional` parameters which unfortunately did not change the issue I'm having. Good note about `cbnumber`, which is not actually a number so I'll take that as a note to name that parameter more clearly.